# How to Hide or Unhide Multiple Worksheets with a Checkbox in excel

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am working in a workbook that has 10 worksheets in it.  I have the main page Sheet10 where I want to put the check boxes to hide/unhide the other worksheets depending upon which checkbox is selected.  I have all other worksheets set as "Very Hidden"  This sheet should be the only one visible when I enter the workbook.  Then once I check one of the Check boxes it unhides the associated worksheets. When it is unchecked it hides those sheets. What is happening everything is showing when I enter the workbook and it hides the worksheets that are not assigned to the check box I am selecting.  When I unchecked  the boxes everything shows.

I have added code to hide and show the worksheets but it isn't working as expected.  It is only Hiding the worksheets it isn't unhiding the hidden sheets as I thought it would.  I have all other worksheets listed as "Very Hidden".  Also, if I click two buttons at the same time it goes funky and doesn't show the right worksheets

**EDIT1**
I added the code below to my macro module.  I am getting errors on the If ctrl area with the multiple sheets to be shown.  When I click on the optionbutton with the macro it gives me a compile error  I must be missing something huge here.

[optionbutton & macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jn0s.jpg)

```
Sub Hide_Sheets()

    Select Case ctrl.Name
        Case "Option Button 1"
            If ctrl.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then nohide = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet4", "Sheet5, "Sheet7", "Sheet9", "Sheet12")
        Case "Option Button 2"
            If ctrl.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then nohide = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5, "Sheet7", "Sheet9", "Sheet12", "Sheet14")
        Case "Option Button 3"
            If ctrl.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then nohide = Array("Sheet13")
    End Select
```

**Edit 2**
I get the following error when I click on one of the option buttons.  I found the issue I missed a ".

[Macro Code Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzRdb.jpg)

**Edit 3**
 The below is the only code I have for this to try and show and hide the worksheets.  It is in my macros module.  With all the back and forth I am not sure if I have what I need now.  I get a Debug error at (If ctrl.FormControlType =). So I have something drastically wrong.  One added note. I cannot unselect any of the option buttons so they are not selected.

```
Sub Hide_Sheets()
    Dim ctrl As Shape, nohide As Variant
    For Each ctrl In Sheets(1).Shapes
        If ctrl.FormControlType = xlOptionButton Then
            Select Case ctrl.Name
                Case "Option Button 1"
                    If ctrl.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then nohide = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet7", "Sheet9", "Sheet12")
                Case "Option Button 2"
                    If ctrl.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then nohide = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet7", "Sheet9", "Sheet12", "Sheet14")
                Case "Option Button 3"
                    If ctrl.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then nohide = Array("Sheet13")
            End Select
        End If
    Next ctrl

    If Not IsEmpty(nohide) Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In Worksheets
             If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, nohide, 0)) Then
                 ws.Visible = False
            Else
                ws.Visible = True
            End If
        Next ws
        nohide = ""
End If

End Sub
```

What I want is a Workbook that has the main page shown when I enter and when I click one of the check boxes it shows or hides the related worksheets. I would like if you select more than one button to add those associated worksheets to visible. When all boxes are unchecked it "Very Hidden" them all.

Comment: So you want `optionbuttons` so only one thing can be checked at a time (would need to have one for "hide all" rather than not have one checked?  It may behoove to simply matters by having a switch where you tell which sheets *shouldn't* be hidden when each option is selected, as to not affect your standard hidden sheets.

Comment: So it would most likely be easier to just make a "Button" and have them show or Hide the sheets?  I am a newbie to vba so I am trying to learn as I go. I would have to create a Hide button as well.  ```Sub hide_()
Sheet3.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet7.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet9.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet10.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet12.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheet13.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheets("Main Page").Activate```

Comment: I was trying to get a clean look with the checkboxes or radio buttons to show and very hide worksheets not needed.

Comment: If you are going to show code, please edit your answer to include, as it is oftentimes unreadable as a comment

Comment: Sorry, I just added the other item I have used in the past but I didn't want to have a button for show and one for hide.  I wanted to try and use Checkboxes or Radio Buttons.  Thanks.

Comment: please indicate what the error you are getting is at `If ctrl.FormControlType = xlOptionButton Then`.   Additionally, what references are you using (in VBA, Tools --> references)?

Comment: my only guess for you atm is to redo the buttons by creating 1 button with the form control button in the dev ribbon of excel then copy/paste/paste for 2 more buttons, which should link them all together.  from there, you would update your code to support the new button names.  sorry if this has been a bit of a chase for you

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend Option Buttons for this as it will be a bit easier, since those on a sheet are automatically linked and only one can be selected at a time (saves error handling on multiple clicked checkboxes)

All buttons are checked to the same macro, where you loop through the shapes on the sheet to determine what is selected to specify what sheets are to be visible (example code):

```
Dim ctrl As Shape, nohide As Variant
For Each ctrl In Sheets(1).Shapes
    If ctrl.FormControlType = xlOptionButton Then
        Select Case ctrl.Name
            Case "Option Button 1"
                If ctrl.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then nohide = Array("Sheet1")    
        End Select
    End If
Next ctrl
```

Then loop through the sheets to hide based on the visible-list:

```
If Not IsEmpty(nohide) Then
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, nohide, 0)) Then
            ws.Visible = False
        Else
            ws.Visible = True
        End If
    Next ws
    nohide = ""
End If
```

---

**Edit1:**

Ensuring you're using the form control, not the activeX or are on a userform... here is how you select the option buttons that are associated with the above syntax:

[image]

Related to having one macro, the purpose was to utilize a switch, `Select Case`, in vba... a switch works that each scenario of a switch is verified and where one is met it is carried out.  for VBA, you are **Selecting** which **Case** is to be utilized.  Here is an example for multiple buttons:

```
    Select Case ctrl.Name
        Case "Option Button 1"
            If ctrl.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then nohide = Array("Sheet1") 
        Case "Option Button 2"
            If ctrl.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then nohide = Array("Sheet1","Sheet2") 
    End Select
```

Note that EVERY case will be assessed, so when you get to the next `ctrl` in the sheet, it might be Option Button 2, so that case will be assessed, but the if-statement will fail and `nohide` will still be what was assigned in the first case, which was true.

Comment: So I would have to create Three Option Buttons one each to "nohide" the sheets I want to show. Put them in the Array area.  The loop is just at the end of the entire script of the 3 total buttons correct?  Will the buttons allow me to deselect them and have it hide them all again?  Sorry I am new to vba...

Comment: @pawcoyote option button form controls (developer tab, insert, select the form control for the option button) will need to be created for every instance of hiding sheets.  The form control option buttons should inherently allow you to only select one at a time on a sheet, so one of your buttons is your default, where only the sheet housing the buttons is not hidden.  You would have a case for each option button you have created.  Make sure to select the option button and see what the name of it is in the address bar (what is written on the button may not be the name).

Comment: I got a "Compile Error" Invalid outside procedure when I put the top code on my Main Page.(For Each ctrl In Sheets(1).Shape))) I added in all the sheets to "nohide" in the Array as well.

Comment: I am getting debug error on this line of code: "If ctrl.FormControlType = xOptionButton1 Then" I have looked at the name of the button and it is as indicated in the xOption area.   How do I look at the optionbutton in the address?  Sorry...

Comment: @pawcoyote i think we've got a different issue; I set you up for using `form controls` on a sheet, however your edit (you attempted to edit my answer, though you need to update your post to includie your attempted code) indicates that you're using a `userform`.  Those each have different syntax.  For `Form Controls` you assign a macro to the button, and each of the option buttons would have assigned the same macro (stored in a standard module labeled like `sub hide_these_sheets`.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry I did copy the code I used.  I will update it again so you can see what I did.  I put three OptionButtons on the cover page and used your code only changing the Array info to include the Sheets to no hide.

Comment: @pawcoyote [edit your own post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57483298/edit), not the answer to your post.  Alright, you are using `form controls`... please only make one (1) macro in your module, where the subroutine reads `Sub Hide_Sheets()`, not private... when you right click on each of the option buttons, assign each to the same macro, `Hide_Sheets`.  You will have in the switch (`Select Case`) MULTIPLE cases... `case "Option Button 1"`, `case "Option Button 2"`, etc.  This is how you would have only one macro for all the efforts.

Comment: @pawcoyote i edited my post to show where i'm coming from.

Comment: Disregard my last update.  I just saw your additional notes.  I am so thankful you are patient with me.

Comment: @pawcoyote just tag me when you get something new; as a recommendation for updating your posts, please indicate **Edit** and input your new information, rather than removing anything from the original post (unless you are editing to correct).  This will ensure that the original question is still available and anyone who might see this down the road has the full story.

Comment: I posted what I am getting now. Thank you for the correct way to post. I created the OptionButton's as you indicted I added the Sub Hide_Sheet () on my macro page and assigned the macro to the buttons. I added in the Sheets into the Array but that turns everything red on that line.  I feel this should be so much easier but I am just not grasping this.  Only one Macro and three buttons.  No other code anywhere else in VBA from what I see.

Comment: @pawcoyote if the line turns red, you should have a message that pops up indicating that you have inappropriate syntax, e.g., you didn't close a quotation or parenthesis.  Please verify that you've used appropriate `array("sheet1","sheet2")`, etc.

Comment: @pawcoyote you dropped the loop... `For Each ctrl In Sheets(1).Shapes`, where `dim ctrl as shape`.  Both parts of the code, the loop through controls, then the hiding of sheets using `nohide` go in `Sub Hide_Sheets()`.

Comment: Hi, I posted the code *EDIT 3* as I thought you had said. I guess I am too much a of newbie for such a code.  I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Am I missing something? I am just not seeing it. Any guidance you can provide is much appreciated.  If a Chat would be better please let me know.